# PSQL check table size when applying where clause

Tags: postgresql

I know I can check the size of a database table by doing this:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('schema.table'));
```

However, is there a way I can query the size of a subsection of the table? For example, all rows where a clause is met:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('schema.table where type = ''ABC''));
```

Something like the above (which obviously doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is direct support for this. The only thing I can think of is to sum the size of the rows that satisfy the condition.

```
select sum(pg_column_size(t)) 
from the_table t
where type = 'ABC';
```

The above does **not** include the size of the indexes which `pg_total_relation_size()` does.